# Erro ao tentar instalar a biblioteca pandas no python 2.7.5

Tags: python, linux, pandas

Estou tentando instalar o pandas no SO Linux, via Moba, mas o retorno abaixo persiste. Já tentei diversas maneiras, porém sem sucesso.

As tentativas:

```
pip install pandas
python -m pip install pandas
python -m pip install pandas
sudo pip install pandas
pip install pandas==0.19.*
sudo apt-get install python-pandas

(base) [root@ ~]# pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/aa/e7078569d20f45e8cf6512a24bf2945698f13a7975650773c01366ea96dc/pandas-1.4.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-OLju22/pandas/setup.py", line 250
        f"{extension}-source file '{sourcefile}' not found.\n"
                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Outras bibliotecas foram instaladas anteriormente, mas o pandas está dando um trabalho.

Comment: Veja a mensagem: `"Using cached"`... Tente instalar sem usar o cache. Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)

Comment: @PauloMarques, eu tentei da forma abaixo, mas sem êxito ainda 

(base) [root@ ~]# pip install --no-cache-dir  pandas==0.19.*
Collecting pandas==0.19.*
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/af/ada95f62d47b72dc0e351aef1b478a9d9d75324a2fddec0c341ce72a937c/pandas-0.19.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 17.2MB 3.1MB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas==0.19.*)

Comment: Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/6c/c0a8130fe198f27bab92f1b28631e0cc2572295f6b7a31e87efe7448aa1c/numpy-1.22.2.zip (11.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 11.4MB 1.1MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-hz1oNY/numpy/setup.py", line 59
        raise RuntimeError(f'Cannot parse version {FULLVERSION}')
                                                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: (base) [root@ ~]# pip list

(...)
click (7.1.2)
configobj (4.7.2)
Cython (0.29.27)
DateTools (1.1)
decorator (3.4.0)
future (0.18.2)
futures (3.3.0)
geomet (0.1.2)
iniparse (0.4)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
IPy (0.75)
kitchen (1.1.1)
perf (0.1)
pip (8.1.2)
policycoreutils-default-encoding (0.1)
pure-sasl (0.6.2)
py4j (0.10.9.1)
pycurl (7.19.0)
pygobject (3.22.0)
pygpgme (0.3)
PyHive (0.6.4)
pyliblzma (0.5.3)
pyparsing (1.5.6)
python-dateutil (2.8.2)
python-linux-procfs (0.4.9)
pyudev (0.15)
pyxattr (0.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

Eu não fazia ideia que tinha predecessor, não tinha o numpy instalado e com o --no-cache-dir na chamada resolveu o problema de cache!

Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).